# Посоветуйте статьи по СУБД

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, postgresql

Умею составлять запросы к MySQL и PostgreSQL, но проблема в том, что так и нет целостной картины по БД и СУБД. Интересно, как всё это работает в памяти и взаимодействует с другими компонентами системы. Все курсы и книги, что читал просто учили строить запросы, не особо углубляясь в основы. Если есть что-то полезное по этой теме, скиньте пожалуйста

Comment: в гугле попробуйте запросом "название-интересующей-БД internals"

Answer (score 1):

*Насколько помню такого плана вопросы не считаются уместными на SO, но всё-таки отвечу.*

Книга `Transactional Information Systems, by Gerhard Weikum and Gottfried Vossen, Morgan Kaufmann` - это увесистое фундаментальное произведение - изложение основных теорий построения СУБД и не только реляционных. Всегда когда у вас появляется задача обеспечения восстановления данных после сбоя, работа в среде конкурентного доступа, атомарности вносимых изменений.

Это одна из пяти книг которую рекомендует сообщество [разработчиков PostgreSQL](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Developer_FAQ#What_books_are_good_for_developers.3F) тем кто бы хотел тоже поучаствовать в разработке этой СУБД. Ещё четыре:

- An Introduction to Database Systems, by C.J. Date, Addison, Wesley A
- Guide to the SQL Standard, by C.J. Date, et. al, Addison, Wesley
- Fundamentals of Database Systems, by Elmasri and Navathe
- Transaction Processing, by Jim Gray and Andreas Reuter, Morgan Kaufmann

Если вам интересно устройство СУБД - то о `Transactional Information Systems` вы ещё определённо услышите. (есть опасность стать DBA)

---

Касательно именно PostgreSQL - начать вероятно стоит с опубликованного [вот здесь материала](http://www.interdb.jp/pg/) и [`internals` раздела](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/internals.html) документации. Ну и по дереву исходного кода: много комментариев, много `README`.